# Create SVN controlled project in-situ

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

I have a project sitting in a archive. The project and files were provided by someone else. The project does not use a version control system. I want to unpack the project and adorn it with versioning. I want to do it in-place so I can make my changes and then `svn diff` to see my changes (and create a diff for a patch).

When I try to place versioning on the unpacked library, I get the following:

```
$ svnadmin create
svnadmin: E205000: Repository argument required
```

And:

```
$ svnadmin create .
svnadmin: E200011: Repository creation failed
svnadmin: E200011: Could not create top-level directory
svnadmin: E200011: '.' exists and is non-empty
```

And:

```
$ svnadmin create `pwd`
svnadmin: E200011: Repository creation failed
svnadmin: E200011: Could not create top-level directory
svnadmin: E200011: '/home/jeffrey/cryptlib-beta' exists and is non-empty
```

I don't want to set up an SVN server or jump through other hoops like checking out from myself (or other steps that make no sense to a regular user who is only concerned about changes/differences).

Is it possible to create a svn version controlled project in-situ? If so, would anyone know the commands?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, translate "in-situ" in plain English

Comment: "In-situ" is "in-place".

Comment: You can't create a repository in the same directory as your source code. That's not how Subversion is designed.

Comment: Thanks Álvaro. Do you know of any tools that allow ups to "create repository" and start working? I swear all I want is a diff after changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You **can't** create repository in non-empty directory
2. You **can't** avoid checkout from repository into Working Copy at least once
3. You **can** don't setup any special SVN-server and use file:/// protocol to access repository

During setup you have to use three directories. Let name it `SOURCE`, `REPO`, `WORK`. Later you'll use only `REPO` and `WORK`

Process step-by-step

- `cd /SOME/PATH`
- `mkdir SOURCE`
- Unpack archive into SOURCE
- `cd /SOME/ANOTHER/PATH`
- `mkdir REPO`
- `cd REPO`
- `svnadmin create .`
- `cd /SOME/PATH/SOURCE`
- `svn import file:////SOME/ANOTHER/PATH/REPO -m "Initial Import"`
- `cd /SOME/ANOTHER-AGAIN/PATH`
- `mkdir WORK`
- `cd WORK`
- `svn co file:///SOME/ANOTHER/PATH/REPO .`
- `rm -r /SOME/PATH/SOURCE`

Edit files in WORK, diff it with base-version, if needed

Comment: Thanks Lazy Badger. Are there any tools that work as I want them to in this situation? I reuse to change my workflow for the tool. (Surely you can't think executing their 15 steps is better than "create now" and start working)

Comment: @noloader - under Windows with TSVN my preparation steps are shorter and include only 4 position. And I don't worry to perform these operations

Comment: @noloader - if you want another tool, it will be not Subversion. In Mercurial, f.e 1) unpack archive 2) `hg init` in archive-tree root 3) `hg add` 4) `hg commit`